# AngularDart: How to force page re-rendering similar to $digest in AngularJS?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have a page with simple component:

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body index-page>

<div>
    <h1>Status</h1>
    <h2>{{ 1 | enum }}</h2>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/web_components/platform.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/web_components/dart_support.js"></script>
<script type="application/dart" src="index.dart"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The filter 'enum' use loads data that using XHR. Therefore, at the page load time the data is available (say, it takes a second). So, while data is not there the filter returns null. How can I trigger the controller to re-evaluate the template when the data is received and the filter is able to return meaningful values?

In the example below I use the Timer to simulate XHR:

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:angular/application_factory.dart';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';


@Controller(selector: '[index-page]', publishAs: 'ctrl')
class IndexPageController {

}

const DELAY = true;

@Formatter(name: 'enum')
class EnumNameFormatter {
    Map names = new Map();

    EnumNameFormatter() {
        if (DELAY) {
            new Timer(new Duration(milliseconds:2000), fillNames);
        } else {
            fillNames();
        }
    }

    void fillNames() {
        names[1] = "One";
        names[2] = "Two";
        names[3] = "Three";
    }

    String call(enumValue) {
        var enumName = names[enumValue];
        if (enumName != null) {
            return enumName;
        }
    }
}

class MyAppModule extends Module {
    MyAppModule() {
        // needed for https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/1272
        // this will be fixed in 14.0
        Binding.printInjectWarning = false;

        // Main controller
        bind(IndexPageController);

        // Formatter
        bind(EnumNameFormatter);

    }
}

void main() {
    applicationFactory().addModule(new MyAppModule()).run();
}
```

In the example below, If I set DELAY = true - "One" is not displayed on the page. If I set DELAY=false - everything works (as it should). How can I force page refresh/re-rendering when the XHR (Timer) was completed?

Answer (score 3):

In AngularDart, you no longer need to use $apply or $digest to re-render the page.  We use Dart Zones to dirty-check your model automatically after any operation.

What you are seeing, is a different bug/feature -- `@Formatters` are idempotent.  That is, we assume that if we have formatted a value once, formatting it again will produce the same result.

Since the expression being formatted: `1` has not changed, we don't re-run the formatter because we assumed it would give the same value.

An easy work-around would be to use a function instead of a formatter.

Comment: The benefit of having a formatter is that you don't have to re-implement or map it for every controller or component. Do you have any suggestions how to implement a global function, that acts like a formatter but is Zone-aware?

Comment: I did some digging. It seems like there's a RootScope object that could be injected into the Formatter. Also, it looks like there's something called WatchGroup that is responsible for detecting the changes. Is it possible to attach a my formatter to a watch group so that it could trigger the update in the template?

Comment: You should be more receptive to the recommendation he gave to not use a formatter at all. Don't try to save time or typing by avoiding structural definitions of functional relations. There are many ways to have functionality provided to many components by one implementation. The first thing I'm thinking of is injecting a service into the components.